# frequency domain phase shift

Tags: fft, frequency-domain

While going through FFT I came to know that, shifting of phase in frequency domain results on shifting of time in time domain.

According to this, in wireless communications, from the transmitter side having 2 antennas,signal s1 transmitted from Ant 1 and phase shifted version of sig2 in frequency domain transmitted from Ant2, sig2 will become a delayed version of sig1. And when both the antennas transmitting sig1 and sig2 at the same time how sig2 will become a delayed version or a multipath component to sig 1.

Comment: What's your question exactly? How to achieve a time shift of sig2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose one signal is $a_1(t) = \cos(\omega t)$ and the other is 
$a_2(t) = \cos(\omega t - \theta)$. Note the
phase shift $\theta$ between the two signals, and note also that we can write
$$a_2(t) = \cos(\omega t - \theta) 
= \cos\left(\omega\left(t-\frac{\theta}{\omega}\right)\right) 
= \cos(\omega (t - t_0)) = a_1(t-t_0)$$
where $t_0 = \frac{\theta}{\omega}$ showing that $a_2(t)$ is a *delayed* version of $a_1(t)$.  Suppose that $a_1(t)$ and $a_2(t)$
are transmitted from the two separate antennas *simultaneously*, that is,
no additional time delay between them, 
and reach the receiver over paths of delays $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$
respectively and gains $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively.
Then the received signals are 
$$\begin{align}
A_1a_1(t-\tau_1) &= A_1\cos(\omega (t -\tau_1)) = A_1\cos(\omega \hat{t})\\
A_2a_2(t-\tau_2) &= A_2\cos(\omega (t -t_0 - \tau_2))\\
&= A_2\cos(\omega (\hat{t} +\tau_1 -t_0-\tau_2))\\
&= A_2\cos(\omega (\hat{t} - (t_0 + \tau_2-\tau_1))\\
&= A_2\cos(\omega \hat{t} -\hat{\theta})
\end{align}$$
where $\hat{t} = t-\tau_1$ is the *time as measured by the receiver clock*.
Thus we see that the second signal is delayed 
*with respect* to the former by $t_0+\tau_2-\tau_1$, that is,
the delay introduced at the transmitter plus the difference in the
delays between the two paths, and this can be expressed as a phase
shift of $\hat{\theta}= \frac{t_0+\tau_2-\tau_1}{\omega}$.

- If $\tau_1 = \tau_2$ so that the
  two paths are of identical lengths, the second signal
  looks like a multipath signal with respect to the first with a delay
  of $t_0$ (equivalently the same phase shift $\theta$ as existed at
  the transmitter).
- If $t_0 = 0$ so that effectively only one signal is
  transmitted, but is received over paths of different lengths,
  the second signal *is* a multipath signal with respect to the first
  with a delay of $\tau_2-\tau_1$ and it too can be expressed
  as a phase shifted version of the first signal.